# Execute VBA from Excel 2010 Ribbon

Tags: vba, excel-2010, ribbon, execute

I have been trying different examples of how to move my VBA buttons into the ribbon but either I the text is flagging red(aka error) or examples relate to doing some xml conversions (never done before so they make no sense).

**All I want to do is move my text coloring buttons into my custom ribbon. When the user clicks on the button icon(inside the Ribbon), the VBA coding executes.**

[image]

As you can see above, currently the Text-Green button on the ribbon...
  when the user clicks it.. it generates a blank Command Button for User to create new Command Buttons. Clearly not what I want.

Any suggestions?

My Blue and Red button coding (simple coding):

```
Private Sub Color_Blue_Click()
    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(83, 141, 213)
End Sub

Private Sub Color_Red_Click()
    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]

I have tried referencing:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I guess it was a simple fix afterall:

I went to:

`Developer Tab/Record Macro`

Named the Macro as `TextGreen`.... clicked `Ok` and once it was saved I clicked `Stop Recording`

Went back to `Developer/Code` Tab and clicked on `Macros`

Then I clicked `Edit` and typed my code there:

```
Sub TextGreen()

  Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)

End Sub
```

[image]

To save to ribbon I did:

Right click `Ribbon/Customize Ribbon`... Selected `Macros` from drop down...saved a group under my Ribbon Tab and Added it.